# Angular JS - UI Grid - import data custom file picker

Tags: angularjs, rest, csv, import, angular-ui-grid

Tried many ways with importFile(grid, fileObject) method in Public Api in module ui.grid.importer. But no success.

I want to import a csv file to the Grid and edit, then post to PHP as Rest link.

Any one help me, give some insight in to it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add CSV.js to your project and then added a reference to it in a script tag? CSV.js is what ui-grid uses by default.

Comment: I can use any csv file importer, but the problem is how to import a csv file from a external file picker, convert the csv through any available library to UI.gird object